# delta.tables module not found

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm trying to import `delta.tables` in my AWS Glue local script but getting error when running:

```
bash gluesparksubmit /home/my_user_name/aws-glue-libs/code/script.py
```

My code for `data_lake_client` that is used in my `script.py` by calling
`from clients import DataLakeClient`:

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from delta.tables import *


class DataLakeClient:
    def __init__(self, s3_alias, prefix):
        self.spark = (
            SparkSession.builder

            .config(
                "spark.jars",
                "/home/my_user_name/aws-glue-libs/code/libs/delta-core_2.12-1.0.0.jar",
            )

            .config(
                "spark.sql.extensions",
                "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension",
            )
            .config(
                "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog",
                "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog",
            )

            .getOrCreate()
        )

        self.path = f"{s3_alias}/{prefix}/"

    def read_dl(self, table):
        return DeltaTable.forPath(self.spark, f"{self.path}/{table}").toDF()
```

Answer (score 1):

To **enable** delta lake in your local Glue container, I am ***assuming*** you are using `Glue 4.0` image which supports `delta-2.1.0`, you need to pass the following parameters along with your `gluesparksubmit`:

1. `--datalake-formats` job parameter with value `delta`
2. To pass `SparkConf` as `--conf` with value `spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog`

As I can see, you are already setting the configuration mentioned in point 2, as spark config you don't need to pass these as a parameter anymore and just passing the parameter mentioned in `point 1` should work for you.

And you might need to pass additional jars in `spark.jars`. That is how it actually works in AWS glue jobs and as the image that is being provided in production ready that should be the case with Local deployments also.